# How to connect or re-link person under specific job role?

Tags: linkedin, invitation

Before when connecting with new people I could see the dropdown whether the person is a friend or colleague, so I could select in which company/role I was working with that person.

Now, I've added a new role under Experience section and I've tried to connect with several people, but it never ask me to which role I'd like to connect them.

Now it shows me this popup:

> You can customize this invitation
>
> LinkedIn members are more likely to accept invitations that include a personal note.

[image: LinkedIn message, You can customize this invitation, LinkedIn members are more likely to accept invitations that include a personal note]

So when I click 'Send now', the invitation is send, but I've no option to associate the person with specific role.

Is this feature has been removed, or there is some setting which I need to change?